# simple/efficient way to expand a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say i have a list and a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(2), 'b': range(2)})
y = [1,2,3]
```

I want to get a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

```
a  b  y
0  0  1
1  1  1
0  0  2
1  1  2
0  0  3
1  1  3
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5401) for the github issue regarding making this simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is called [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). Convert to dataframe

```
>>> y = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list('y'))
```

add constant key

```
>>> x['k'] = 1
>>> y['k'] = 1
```

and merge over it

```
>>> pd.merge(y, x, on='k')[['a', 'b', 'y']]
   a  b  y
0  0  0  1
1  1  1  1
2  0  0  2
3  1  1  2
4  0  0  3
5  1  1  3
```